# Mapping to com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point invalid endian flag

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgis, spatial

I am working on a project where I will be retrieving a user's latitude and longitude.  From this, I would like to store it into the database as a Point.  However, when I attempt to do so I have run into the following error:  `o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered.`

I am taking the model which is exposed to client side and mapping it as follows:

```
 public static Point createPoint(double longitude, double latitude){
        GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();

        Coordinate coord = new Coordinate(longitude, latitude );
        Point point = gf.createPoint( coord );

        return point;
    }
```

So I would call this method roughly as follows to map the value as a Point:

```
createPoint(user.getLocation().getLongitude(), user.getLocation().getLatitude());
```

Which I would then store the returned value into the database.

My pom file has the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
        <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
        <version>1.13</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
          <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

jpa configuration:

```
jpa:
        database: POSTGRESQL
        open-in-view: false
        show-sql: true
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: none
            dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
            naming:
                naming-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringNamingStrategy
```

Column definition:

```
@Column(name="point")
private com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point point;
```

Any ideas as to how I can fix this error?
Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: Not sure if understood your correctyl, but is not `javax.persistence.AttributeConverter` what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can accomplish this and it all depends on precisely how you'd like the data to be stored in the underlying data store.

As pointed out in the comments, you could use an `AttributeConverter` implementation to store the `x`, `y`, and `z` components of the `Point`'s coordinates in a single column delimited by some magic character:

```
public class PointerConverter implements AttributeConverter<Point, String> {
   @Override
   public String converToDatabaseColumn(Point point) {
     // read the x, y, z, construct a string delimited by some character and
     // return the value.  Hibernate will store this in your column.
   }

   @Override
   public Point convertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
     // split the value by the delimiter and construct a Point.
     // return the constructed Point to be set in the entity.
   }
}
```

One of the inherent problems with this approach is that it makes querying against the various parts of the `Point`'s coordinates nearly impossible.

If you find you need to be able to query against a `Point` and supply the various `x`, `y`, or `z` values that make up the `Point`'s coordinates then you'll be better off considering:

- A custom `UserType` implementation
- Using an `@Embeddable` to represent your `Point` in the persistence world.

For a custom `UserType`, you'd need to define a new type, likely called `PointType` in this example that extends `UserType`, and reference  it like the following:

```
@Type(type = "PointType")
@Columns({@Column(name = "X"), @Column(name="Y"), @Column(name="Z"))
private Point point;
```

The custom `UserType` would handle mapping the `x`, `y`, and `z` portions of the point's coordinates to the appropriate columns `X`, `Y`, and `Z` and vice versa.

For an `@Embeddable` solution, you'd just create your own `JpaPoint` class which you can pass in your geometry `Point` class for it to read the `x`, `y`, and `z` values and store those in 3 properties for the persistence model.  The `JpaPoint` class could then also expose a helper method allowing the caller to generate a `Point` from the `JpaPoint` embeddable:

```
// ctor example
public JpaPoint(Point point) {
  this.x = point.getCoordinates().x;
  this.y = point.getCoordinates().y;
  this.z = point.getCoordinates().z;
}

// helper method
@Transient
public Point getPoint() {
  return new Point( new Coordinates( x, y, z ) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your in depth response.  I have further attempted to create another utility class to do conversion from lon/lat into a `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point point` using a WKTReader & writer and still no luck. I'm going to play around with your last idea and instead create an embeddable point as you suggested - this should do the trick.  Thanks again!

Comment: Please, can you put your AttributeConverter for JPAPoint (Embeddable) to Point (vividsolutions)? Thank You